# Converting es6 react variable to round to the nearest 10th

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
const percent = (props.students.length / totalStudentsProgram) * 100;
```

It returns 44.444444444444% How can I round it so that it looks like 44.4%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `.toFixed` will return a string with the appropriate number of decimal places.

```
var str = percent.toFixed(1) + '%';
```